# How do I clean my sticky floor after a party night?

Tags: cleaning, home

I held a New Year's party at my home, and my house was left a mess, afterwards. There's dirt, glitter and sticky confetti all over the floor, as well as the remains of different drinks that were dropped.

What's the best way to clean all that junk off of my floor?

After three times of cleaning it with a dust mop and floor cleaner it is still sticky when walking over.

Comment: Did you mix the floor cleaner in a bucket with water, or use neat?

Comment: I mix(ed) it with water.

Comment: Answer: don't let it happen

Comment: Ha ha, very funny ;) it was New Years Eve... You do not have control of anything on a house party!

Comment: I hate to say it, but this might be a hands and knees job - scrubbing brush and soapy bucket, plus another bucket with cloths and clean water. Scrub with soapy mix, take a cloth from the water bucket, mop it up. The stickiness of the drinks is still on the floor if you just use one bucket with diluted floor cleaner and a mop, all you're doing is spreading it around. Or use two different mops for each bucket...I hope the party was worth it!

Comment: Since cleaning it with a mop and floor cleaner doesn't work, it means you'll need a really heavy duty solution which means there likely isn't a lifehack way to do it

Comment: Therefore both of those down votes? Hm... Okay, it'll probably be Bamboo's solution. Thank you anyways! And let me tell you, the party was worth it - totally :)

Comment: put down some plastic all throughout the house like painters do when painting. When party is over, just roll the plastic from the edges to the inside and throw in garbage.

Comment: I don't agree or understand the closure on this question, and so I've made a [meta](http://meta.lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/1346/why-was-this-question-about-cleaning-a-sticky-floor-closed-as-off-topic). It would be greatly appreciated if the users who voted to close could weigh in with their reasoning.

Comment: Thank you Wipqozn, I'm not sure what I did wrong either. I'll be waiting patiently.

Comment: I've edited your question for clarity; please check that my edits don't confer any misinformation about your question. You might want to [edit] in what kind of floor you have, because there are different ways to clean carpet, tile etc.

Comment: Tip for you: if you want to make sure someone knows about your response to their comment, write their username, preceded by the `@` symbol. I'm not sure that @Wipqozn saw your response to their comment.

Comment: @Shokhet alright, thank you very much for all the tips! I will check and edit my post asap.

Comment: @pLoory So, what kind of floor do you have? What kind of floor cleaner did you use (if available the working chemical is the most interesting thing as the specific brand will be unknown to many people)? What kinds of drinks (sugary / alcoholic / fatty / milky) were spilled? Did mopping it change the spills at all or were they set like stone? Keep in mind that cleaning fat from carpet is totally different from cleaning sugar from tiles.

Answer (score 5):

Do the following steps, repeating as necessary.

> 1. Get a mop or cleaning device.
> 2. Get a bucket or liquid storage device.
> 3. Mix the following in the bucket (or liquid storage device):
>
>    - **4 parts water**
>    - **2 parts bleach/vinegar**

Apply with mop as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Hire a cleaning service. They're experts when it come to cleaning, and have the proper tools and skills one needs for cleaning up any mess.

Answer (score 0):

With a party game.
See who can clean the floor the best with soap and water.